# How to parse Facebook score data into Strings in Monotouch iOS?

Tags: facebook, xamarin.ios

I have this facebook data:

```js
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "James Pearce", 
        "id": "738229837"
      }, 
      "score": 20, 
      "application": {
        "name": "Bubble Safari", 
        "namespace": "bubblesafari", 
        "id": "164731003644283"
      }
    },
    ...
```

And i want to parse this data into strings.I'm getting this data from this listener from result object:

```cs
FBRequestConnection.StartWithGraphPath(AppId+"/scores?fields=score,user",null,"GET", 
(FBRequestConnection connection, NSObject result, NSError err) => {
    if (err != null)
        ShowMessage("Error", string.Format ("Error:\nDomain: {0}\nCode: {1}\nDescription: {2}", err.Domain, (FBErrorCode)err.Code, err.Description));
});
```

How can i parse this data into strings?

Answer (score 3):

This is Json formatted data.  Use the [JSON.Net](http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/) component to parse the data, then you can access the individual members.

```
string data = ... whatever the FB response is ...
var parsed = JObject.Parse (data);

var user = data["data"]["user"];
var name = user["name"];
var score = data["data"]["score"];
```